# how do i list all the attribute name in an xml using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

Using powershell how do I get the list of attributeNames.

```
  <productSettings>
    <productGroups>
      <productGroup attributeName1="1" 
                    attributeName2="1" 
                    attributeName3="xyz" 
                    attributeName4="0"/>
    </productGroups>
  </productSettings>
```

When I try to use the Atrributes property I get the attribute values not the name of the attribute

```
[xml]$config = Get-Content 'C:\\ProductGroup.config'

$configNodes = $config.productSettings.productGroups.ChildNodes

foreach($configNode in $configNodes)
{
    $configNode.Attributes
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditional approach: Iterate the attributes and output their names:

```
foreach ($configNode in $configNodes) {
    foreach ($attr in $configNode.Attributes) {
        $attr.Name
    }
}
```

PowerShell approach: In PowerShell 3.0+ you can use dot notation on collections to access nested properties:

```
foreach ($configNode in $configNodes) {
    $configNode.Attributes.Name
}
```

---

In fact you could go as far as

```
$config.productSettings.productGroups.productGroup.Attributes.Name
```

which would produce *all* attribute names across *all* `<productGroup>` elements, i.e. it would be equivalent to XPath

```
/productSettings/productGroups/productGroup/@*/name()
```